# change capybara driver without restarting spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, cucumber, capybara, spork

I am running integration tests for my Rails app using Cucumber with Capybara. I also use Spork for faster test runs. Capybara supports **selenium** and the headless **poltergeist**. Headless browser is good for faster test runs, but sometimes I also need to view what the browser is showing. This leads me to changing the Capybara driver and restarting spork.

Is there a way to change the Capybara driver without restarting spork?

**Things that I have tried**

[1] Added a module containing the driver code in features/support and referred that in Spork's each_run. It does not work and throws up an error.

[2] Using each_run to change the driver does not register the change until spork is restarted.

```
Spork.each_run do
  Capybara.javascript_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

Comment: Would screenshots be OK instead of live viewing the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out. [Capybara's github page](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara#drivers) had some information on this. Here's what I did:

Added the following code to **features/support/hooks.rb**

```
Before('@javascript') do
  Capybara.current_driver = :poltergeist
end
```

This can be changed at any point without needing a Spork restart. I was unable to figure out a way to place it in the each_run block.